# OneNote to Word : keeping headings

Tags: ms-word, onenote

I'd like to convert a note I wrote in OneNote to Word.
I have investigated the options "send to" and "save as" and it is filling only part of my need (my notes are in Word).

I use headings in OneNote (using OneNote styles, eg via ctrl + alt + 1).
These headings are not properly converted as Word Headings during the export : 
- I have some formatting of the text ...
- but this is just formating, and there not any more information about the structure

how can I keep heading/hierarchy information during the export ?

Answer (score 0):

the answer has been provided on MS forums [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-onenote/onenote-to-word-keeping-headings/d4a6f558-d9bc-4fb8-a6cd-78240336f506).
this feature is not supported by onenote, because of the way onenote handles styles.

Answer (score 0):

The styles 'Heading 1' to 'Heading 6' now appear to be correctly exported by OneNote 2016 when exporting to `.docx` format. Other styles 'Normal', 'Code', and 'Citation' don't export as their own styles, however, and 'Quote' appears as 'Normal' style in Word but italicised.